# Possibly to release multiple changes at once in Azure?

Tags: azure, deployment

Current scenario:

- Release changes to our infrastructure
- Release changes to our web api/Azure Functions app which *then* respects the infrastructure changes in the previous step

The problem is that, for an arbitrary amount of time - between the 2 steps, we have an out of sync issue. The change has been made to the infrastructure, the web API/azure functions app for a moment is throwing all kinds of exceptions since the infrastructure it references has now changed.

### Question

Is it possible in Azure to somehow release everything at once and then flick the environment over to the newly released one, for example?

### Example

For the sake of the question, an example might be:

- Change the name of a table in table storage and release that name change
- Reflect this change in the web API and release that web API

Comment: Can you elaborate on what infra references that you Azure Functions is referring to? Are those references not part of App Settings?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. @Prawin - even if they were, there is still some delay between changing what's being referenced and changing the app setting. A small delay, granted, but would cause downtime. For the sake of elaborating - one instance might be a service bus subscription that changes. But I guess my question is agnostic of anything specific like that, it's basically how do I change multiple things in an environment without causing downtime. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you explain how you are releasing? is it a manual process or you are using Azure Devops?

Comment: If it's a manual process, i highly recommend you to leverage Azure DevOps (1) Create the complete Infra + App Settings + Any other settings using ARM Templates (2) Deploy the package (Azure Functions / APIs) using the appropritate Release tasks available in Azure DevOps first to a Staging Slot (3) Swap the Slots - This way, you are solving two problems (1) Even if there are any infra changes that your code is referring it there wouldn't be any issue to the Production users as you are first deploying it to staging. (2) When you use the Swap feature, there is no downtime.